# How to add more levels to score in optaplanner other than Hard medium and soft?

Tags: optaplanner

I have HardMediumSoftScore, I want to add one more level (4 stages)
Hard, Hardmedium, medium and soft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `BendableScore`, which has configurable number of hard and soft score levels.

For more information check [related section](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.0.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#bendableScore) in OptaPlanner documentation.